# HTML5 Audio onLoad

Tags: html, audio

How can I get a callback when the audio tag is ready to play. (to tell the user, when implementing my own controls)

Using Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have only done this on the video element but it should work for audio.

Firstly, you can't bind the event, I don't know why that doesn't work. So you have to use setTimeout.

Example using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var audioReady = function(){
        if (youraudioelement.attr('readyState')) {
            alert("it's ready!");
        } else {
            setTimeout(audioReady, 250);
        }
    }
    audioReady();
}
```

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#the-ready-states

Comment: Not optimal, but I suppose there's no other choice... Thanks

Comment: Just checked the 'loadeddata' event and it works well in the latest versions of IE, Chrome and FF. Haven't tested older browsers or mobile  yet.

Answer (score 4):

Can you not bind to the `onloadeddata` event? It works for me. [W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#event-mediacontroller-loadeddata)

Comment: This is the better anwser

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the canplaythrough event?