# JavaScript audio not playing outside of jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I know the question title doesn't make much sense, but I can't think of a better way to put it. I am a newbie to jQuery and I'm using this code to fade in a `<div>` and play a sound:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#speech').fadeIn('medium', function() {

        play('msg_appear');

        var sptx = $('<p class="stext">').text('There is nothing here.');

        $('#speech').append(sptx);
        $('.stext').typeOut({marker: '', delay: 22});

    });

});
```

This code runs fine however the sound plays *after* the fade-in is complete. I wanted it to play while it was fading in, so I tried placing the `play()` call outside of the fade-in function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    play('msg_appear');

    $('#speech').fadeIn('medium', function() {
```

However, now it's not playing at all. There's no errors on the JavaScript console so I'm unsure if it's a syntax error, and probably something obvious, but I don't know what.

`play()` is a function I found to play audio, here it is if it matters at all. I placed it in the same file the above code is; right above the `$(document).ready()`.

```
function play(sound) {

    if (window.HTMLAudioElement) {
      var snd = new Audio('');

      if(snd.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) {
        snd = new Audio(sound + '.ogg');
      }
      else if(snd.canPlayType('audio/mp3')) {
        snd = new Audio(sound + '.mp3');
      }

      snd.play();
    }
    else {
      alert('HTML5 Audio is not supported by your browser!');
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's unexpected... Try replacing `ready(` with `on('click',` and see if it works. It looks like it's related to timing. And check in another browser

Comment: That works, however I wanted it to play as soon as the page is loaded, not once it has been clicked.

Comment: The first way you tried works incorrectly because the callback function only happens when the fade animation has completed, so the second way is correct. I cannot replicate the error though; it plays fine for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Chromium snapshot from a few months ago.

Comment: Reload the page with the Network tab visible in Developer Tools, then post whether your browser requests the audio file, and whether the status is "pending" or otherwise.

Comment: `msg_appear.ogg` appears with status Success and type Pending, and then right under it another request for the same file appears as status Canceled.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Work and all that. Try adding `snd.load();` before `snd.play();`. That cancelled request implies that network latency is preventing the audio file to be loaded in time for the `play();` (I know it's marked as solved, but this may lead to a more robust solution)

Comment: @joequincy - With what, sometimes the div doesn't fade in at all, although the sound still plays.

Comment: Actually, disregard that, I had the wrong element ID to fade-in. But now the sound won't play. A solution that works is both the `snd.load();` combined with the delay from the accepted answer, so I'll go with that. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my solution. Apparently directly setting the `oncanplay` property of an audio object fails for no apparent reason in some browsers. Using `addEventListener` works universally though. /shrug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think that `$(document).ready` is too early to allow play to happen (in whichever browser is exhibiting this problem), when not delayed by the `fadeIn`.

Try :

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    play('msg_appear');
    $('#speech').fadeIn('medium', function() {
        var sptx = $('<p class="stext">').text('There is nothing here.');
        $('#speech').append(sptx);
        $('.stext').typeOut({marker: '', delay: 22});
    });
});
```

### EDIT:

If necessary, you can introduce further delay as follows:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        play('msg_appear');
        $('#speech').fadeIn('medium', function() {
            var sptx = $('<p class="stext">').text('There is nothing here.');
            $('#speech').append(sptx);
            $('.stext').typeOut({marker: '', delay: 22});
        });
    }, 1000);//adjust up/down to the minimum reliable value
});
```

Comment: Excellent. With the setTimeout in place, you may be able to revert to `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: I hope you are aware that this kind of solution can fail randomly. There must be a way to query the audio object to see if it is ready to play

Comment: @naugtur, the problem then might be that you're into something even less reliable until HTML5 media events have been totally sorted out in all the common browsers. See **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Media_events)** for example. "canplaythrough" would be a good event to respond to in this case, but appears to be proprietary.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, I'd recommend modifying the `play()` function you found:

```
function play(sound, callback) {
    if (window.HTMLAudioElement) {
        var snd = new Audio('');
        if(snd.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) {
            snd = new Audio(sound + '.ogg');
        }
        else if(snd.canPlayType('audio/mp3')) {
            snd = new Audio(sound + '.mp3');
        }
        if(typeof(callback)=="function"){
            snd.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
                snd.play();
                callback();
            });
        } else {
            snd.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
                snd.play();
            });
        }
        snd.load();
    }
    else {
        alert('HTML5 Audio is not supported by your browser!');
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
play('msg_appear', function(){
    $('#speech').fadeIn('medium', function() {

        var sptx = $('<p class="stext">').text('There is nothing here.');

        $('#speech').append(sptx);
        $('.stext').typeOut({marker: '', delay: 22});

    });
});
```

That way the audio's `play();` won't fire until after the audio can start playing, and the `fadeIn()` will be started at the same time as the audio.
And of course, the callback isn't necessary; it just makes for more robust timing in varying network conditions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see: [HTML5 Audio onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335064/html5-audio-onload)
There are some ways to handle loading state. The accepted answer looks weird though.

I recommend code like this:

```
function makePlayer(sound){
  if (window.HTMLAudioElement) {
      var snd = new Audio('');

      if(snd.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) {
        snd = new Audio(sound + '.ogg');
      }
      else if(snd.canPlayType('audio/mp3')) {
        snd = new Audio(sound + '.mp3');
      }

      return function(){
        snd.play();
      };
    }

};

var play = makePlayer('msg_appear');

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#speech').fadeIn('medium', function() {

        play();

        var sptx = $('<p class="stext">').text('There is nothing here.');

        $('#speech').append(sptx);
        $('.stext').typeOut({marker: '', delay: 22});

    });

});
```