# JavaScript/HTML - Alert box goes before sound?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

The code:

```
x = new Audio("bar.wav")

x.play()

alert("foo")
```

Why does the alert box show up first and then then sound is played??

Comment: Because it takes some time for the sound file to load.

Comment: Yes IK but how can I fix it?, I tried with timeout and it worked but is there any other solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Audio onLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335064/html5-audio-onload)

Comment: Try `x.onplay = function() { alert('foo'); };`

Answer (score 3):

That's because the sound file is loaded asynchronously by JavaScript and then the code continues to execute. The alert fires first because it takes a while to load the sound file.

To fix it, you need to add an event listener on load, like so:

```
x.addEventListener('load', function() {
    x.play();
    alert("foo");
});
```

Or you could add the event listener to the `onplay` event, like so:

```
x.onplay = function () { alert("foo"); };
x.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the playing event. Thats when the sound actually starts playing.
But just an advice that alert boxes pause code execution and could really mess up with sound.

```
x = new Audio("bar.wav")
x.onplaying = function ()
{
  alert("foo");
}
x.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: on this post, a `onloadeddata` event is used, its more intesting than the example below, but i havent tested it: [HTML5 Audio events not triggering on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790091/html5-audio-events-not-triggering-on-chrome)

--

As you can't assign an `onload` event, you have to do this:

```
$(function(){
    youraudioelement = new Audio("bar.wav")
    var audioReady = function(){
        if (youraudioelement.attr('readyState')) {
            alert("foo");
        } else {
            setTimeout(audioReady, 250);
        }
    }
    audioReady();
}
```

[HTML5 Audio onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335064/html5-audio-onload)

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
x.onended = function () { alert("foo"); };
x.play();
```